# How do I associate or assign a large amount of continuous variables with zero-heavy distributions to different groups?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, zero-inflation, discriminant-analysis, association-measure

I have a dataset with about 70 continuous numeric variables. I have about 80 samples which divide more or less equally into two groups. I want to figure out which of these variables is most strongly associated with the groupings so that I can focus on just a few of these for further analyses.

The main problem is that the values for the variables are all very small and there are many zeros (possibly zero-inflated). In some cases, almost all samples have a measure of zero for a given variable. A measure of zero is likely not a "true" zero; it just means that the machine (chromatography) was not able to detect a measurable quantity. I have removed any variables that have zero variance. Since my data does not conform to the assumptions of most standard analysis approaches, I cannot apply a discriminant analysis or a canonical correlation analysis reliably. I have done a basic PCA but I am not sure if this the best approach. I have looked into other machine learning approaches such as SVM or classification trees but am unsure whether these are appropriate for my dataset. Here is a plot of the distribution of the variables:
[image: Distribution of variables for all samples]

Here is the PCA biplot with all the variables and samples separated by group:
[image: PCA biplot]

Obviously I can just remove the variables that are almost all zeros, but many that have maybe half of the observations as zero could still be useful. What would be the most appropriate analysis to find which variables best associate to each group?

Comment: If the goal is to discriminate between two groups, maybe look into logistic regression (search this site), possibly with regularization

Comment: Thanks, I looked into logistic regression, but I am not sure if it is able to take into account so many different variables? Another tack I took was to remove variables with excessive amounts of zeros when the zeros were evenly distributed between categories, then transformed the data and used a mixed linear model approach to determine significance for each variable individually.